# Access a IBOutlet id defined in one class in another

Tags: objective-c, macos, class, nsview, iboutlet

Hello I have an IBOutlet id which is used for a view it's defined in a class, I need to access it from another class how can I do this?

I'm still learning ObjC so I appreciate your patience with me as i'm trying to learn as much as possible!

To add more context: I have a controller which is where my view IBOutlet is defined, I then have a class which does some drawing - I need to use dataWithPDFInsideRect on the view from the other class as part of my drawing.

I've so far i've created an instance of the controller but not sure how to access the IBOutlet from that.

`MyController *saveTextViewController = [[MyController alloc] init];`

Comment: What's the relationship between your two view controller objects? `[[MyController alloc] init]` probably not what you're looking for. It will create a *new* instance of `MyController`, which will be complete unrelated to the existing instance that was made when your app loaded its nib/storyboard

Comment: Ok so sounds like i'm on the wrong track - could you clarify what you mean by the relationship - apologies i'm still new to ObjC

Comment: It doesn’t really have anything to do with Objective C, specifically. So you have a piece of data (e.g. I’m this case, some object that’s referenced by an IBoutlet of one view controller instance), that you would like to make accessible to another view controller instance. The question is: why do you want to do that? Does one view controller contain the other? Are the two VCs siblings of some third, “parent” VC? The exact semantic relationship between the two VCs, and what you’re trying to achieve by sharing this data, will determine the best course of action

Comment: Is the outlet a property? What is preventing you from accessing the outlet?

Answer (score 0):

IB Outlets are used to link information created from a ".xib" file to runtime values in your code.  If your `MyController` would only have an IBOutlet value if you intended to create an instance of it by loading it from an interface builder file, not create it with alloc and init.

If you did load `MyController` from the xib file, and in that xib file the outlet was linked to another view that was also loaded from the xib file then at runtime the value of the outlet would be set to the second view automatically.

Read the documentation on:

[Connecting Objects to Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ConnectingObjectstoCode.html)